# Where to find Microsoft Store Submission Details?

Tags: publish, publishing, xamarin.uwp

When I want to publish my XF.UWP app to the Microsoft store on a new pc I am presented with the following fields to fill:

- Tenant ID
- Client ID
- Client Key

The [Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) that guides you through the process seems to be outdated (I already reported this), and I can't find the data that I need to fill from the new Microsoft Partner Center.

The only field I am able to find is 'Tenant Id'. I Found it under gear icon - account settings - organisation profile - tennants.

Who can help me out

[image]

Comment: Have you registered a Developer Account, either individual or company-based ?
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/register/

Comment: yes, my app is already in the store, I'm trying to update it from a fresh pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with many of Microsoft's services, the Client ID/ Client Key location is a bit vague and easier to explain with screenshots than words. But for anyone who may not understand the purpose, I'll leave a brief synopsis to explain the caveman drawings below.

The tenant ID in this scenario is the ID of your Azure AD tenant. No big surprises here. You can grab this (assuming an Azure AD organization is already linked to your Microsoft Partner Center account) from the [MPC dashboard](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/home) under [Home > Account Settings > Organization profile > Tenants](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/v3/tenantmanagement#commercial).

The client ID & client key are slightly harder to locate. This is because MPC recognizes three types of entities within the user hierarchy.

1. Users
2. Groups
3. Azure AD applications

To take advantage of the current automated publishing pipeline for the Microsoft Store, you must create or manage the Azure AD application associated with your project, which can be done under [Home > Account settings > User management > Azure AD applications](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/v3/usermanagement#apps).

If you are familiar with GCP or Google API integration, the Azure AD app is the equivalent of a service account. A given Azure AD application can be assigned any permission within the scope of your project or even your organization based on the scenario. In my experience, the Manager role has always been sufficient.

Click an existing app to manage or create a new one from scratch; either way, you will soon reach the Client ID / Client Key panel, where you can add, view (one time only), and delete keys for your application. The values generated here can be utilized in the Microsoft Store submission workflow seen in the OP's screenshot above. Happy publishing!

[image: locating the Tenant ID]

[image: locating the Client ID/Client key (1 of 3)]

[image: locating the Client ID/Client key (2 of 3)]

[image: the Client ID/Client key management screen (3 of 3)]

References: [Add users, groups, and Azure AD applications to your Partner Center account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/add-users-groups-and-azure-ad-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Azure AD` linked to your account?

If so, those keys should be available here:
https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/v3/usermanagement#users

If not, it can be configured here:
https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/TenantSetup

leading to:
https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/Account/CreateTenant